# How to get the source from a onClick event with Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I'm starting with Android Studio, and I wanted to make an easy app which writes the text of the button pressed to a text. The problem is I can't get the source from the onClick event. Here is my kt file:

```
fun buttonClick(view: View){
    //textet.text = ¿?
}
```

Here the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textet"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buleriaButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="27dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="100dp"
    android:background="#CDDC39"
    android:onClick="buttonClick"
    android:text="Buleria"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/sanmiguelButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="33dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="152dp"
    android:background="#A86868"
    android:onClick="buttonClick"
    android:text="SanMiguel"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/buleriaButton"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/allevoyButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="37dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="29dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="27dp"
    android:onClick="buttonClick"
    android:text="Allevoy"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/sanmiguelButton"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I want to access to the attribute "text" of the button I clicked to write it on "textet".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to cast the view in the function  parameter to Button using the `as` operator after checking if is button type in case that same function is accesed by other views using the `is`, then get the text from it as follows:-

```
fun buttonClick(view: View){
       val button : Button = view as Button
       textet.text = button.text
    }
```

Comment: Yup, this worked. It's not a Button, but AppCompatButton, so if I cast to that, it works as I wanted.